# Symfony 2.7 / 3 - Doctrine: You have requested a non-existent service "fos_user.doctrine_registry"

Tags: doctrine, fosuserbundle, symfony, symfony-2.7, symfony-2.8

Doing a composer update today suddenly getting the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>   You have requested a non-existent service
>   "fos_user.doctrine_registry".

when composer is executing the `cache:clear --no-warmup` command.

Search found an answer related to converting from doctrine to MongoDB but the solutions are not working for me. I am using Doctrine. I've tried Fosuserbundle dev-master, dev-master@dev, 2.0.0-alpha1 and 2.0.0-alpha3.

Any other suggestions? Composer update was working fine a couple of days ago.

Comment: Yes also experiencing this... will keep debugging and see what I find.

Comment: While this question is tagged as symfony2, according to the comments below the answer the problem exists with Symfony 2.7 and 2.8 too.

Comment: Originally tagged as Symfony 3, but appears applicable to various Symfony 2 versions as well as noted below.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Issue created here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2048

**Short term fix** (worked for me Symfony 3.0.* ) :

```
services:
    fos_user.doctrine_registry:
        alias: doctrine
```

Comment: Thanks for @xabbuh, for this fix! It is not working for 3.0 (possibly 2.8 too) though.

Comment: Thanks. Has worked for me. I am using Symfony 3.0.* and fosuserbundle "dev-master@dev"

Comment: Worked for me on Symfony 2.7.8. Thanks!

Comment: This works but my production cache won't clear following this update either. I get the error:

Class 'FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\Orm\UserListener' not found in ../app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 442

Comment: It works thanks, be sure to import app/config/service.yml on app/config/config.yml, otherwise put this on your service.yml bundle

Comment: is nobody testing before to commit in symfony(fos)? ahh php bad practices :)

Comment: I had this problem as well with Symfony 3.0.1. After upgrading to Symfony 3.0.2 everything worked flawlessly - creating a service alias wasn't necessary.

Comment: I had this issue after I ran composer update on 2.6.9. This fixed the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

My solution work like a charm... All works with huge mongo dataset

FIX For MongoDB using ODM:

```
# FIX doctrine registry service for 3.0 and 2.8 sf version
fos_user.doctrine_registry:
    alias: doctrine_mongodb
```

Comment: great work. only post I've seen about mongodb doctrine alias